# Base64 Encoded SVG Image as Background-Image CSS Property

Tags: css, svg, sass, base64

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, I want to use SVG graphic as background-image, encoded in base64. I used [yoksel.github.io](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/) to encode the graphic, however, the graphic is not visible.

```
  .borderCurve
    position: absolute
    bottom: -20px
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 141 19'%3E%3Cpath d='M366-589c-6 1-11 5-16 9-6 7-10 16-10 26 0 20-15 36-34 36h-411c-9 0-18-4-24-10-7-7-10-16-10-26 0-17-12-31-27-35h532z' fill='rgba(255,255,255,0.7)'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A")
    background-size: contain
    background-position: center top
    background-repeat: no-repeat
    width: 158px
    height: 20px
    opacity: 0.7
```

If I replace the svg graphic with a jpg encoded in base64, it works fine & the graphic is visible, however, the SVG is not visible. With the SVG encoded data, Firefox doesn't flag the `background-image` property as invalid, however, it does show it as have dimensions of `0 0`.

How do I display the encoded SVG using `background-image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the value for the `viewBox` to `viewBox='-166 -589 532 71'` since yours (`viewBox='0 0 141 19'`) will put the shape far away outside the svg canvas. I hope it helps.

```css
.borderCurve{
    /*position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;*/
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='-166 -589 532 71'%3E%3Cpath d='M366-589c-6 1-11 5-16 9-6 7-10 16-10 26 0 20-15 36-34 36h-411c-9 0-18-4-24-10-7-7-10-16-10-26 0-17-12-31-27-35h532z' fill='red' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 158px;
    height: 20px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    outline:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="borderCurve"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it!